# Receiving image file as byte[] and save it again in image file

Tags: json, rest

I want to convert get byte[] of an image file from the JSON response and set convert that byte[] to image file again. How can i proceed with it ? can someone give a me small example of it.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Yes. I want to know in Java